# Solving nonlinear Diophantine equations such as (8+3n)m = 11?

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic, algebra

Are there any efficient algorithms that could be used to generate all integer solutions to equations such as the ones below?

- (8+3n)m = 11 | n ∈ {0,1}, m ∈    ℤ+
- (5+(7+3x+2y)a+3z)b = 30 | x,y,z ∈ {0,1}, a,b ∈ ℤ+

Ideally I would like to be able to generate the set of all valid integer values for n,m and a,b,x,y,z respectively. At the very least I would like a way of testing if the equations are solvable at all. Given that these equations are nonlinear I would imagine that typical methods used to solve simple Diophantine equations would fail here.

I would really appreciate any help I could get!

Comment: This gets hard quick - see https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/17478/diophantine-equations-and-complexity-classes

Comment: Is it coincidence that in your examples, all coefficients are positive and there is only an integer on the right hand side? If this number is not too large and there is a limited numberof variables, a brute-force approach could be the best option.

Comment: That is _not_ a coincidence, for my simple cases, the coefficients will always be positive and there will always be a relatively small integer on the right hand side. I imagined brute-force might be my only option but I was hoping for something a bit more elegant. Thank you both for your responses!

Answer (score 0):

Since 11 is prime, there are only 4 possible factorizations in Z:

```
8+3n=11 and m=1
8+3n=1 (impossible) and m=11
8+3n=-11 (impossible) and m=-1
8+3n=-1 m=-11
```

By restricting n in {0,1} only one solution remains...

For second case, there are quite more possibilities, since 30 is 2*3*5, you will have 16 possible products for your two terms in Z...

If you replace (x,y,z) by their 8 possible combinations, the first term degenerates in a 1st order polynomial in a, so that's only 8*16 = 128 polynomials to test for an integer root.

If all the problems degenerate in a product of polynomials of one variable after substitution of the variables that are in finite set (by brute force), then it's like finding integer roots of polynomials, which is trivial for 1st order polynomials like in the two problems above, and equivalent to factor a polynomial over the integers for higher degree...

If the factors remain multivariate, but linear (total order 1), then it's like solving linear systems. But finding integer solutions is not necessarily trivial, I recommend reading http://sites.math.rutgers.edu/~sk1233/courses/ANT-F14/lec3.pdf

Else if factors remain multivariate and of total order > 1, that's equivalent to solving polynomial systems... In some cases, that's possible, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gr%C3%B6bner_basis.